# Properly setup a DNS Fallback

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ipv4

My country just ordered the Internet Access Providers to blacklist some domain names from their respective DNS (i.e. responding to t411.io by 127.0.0.1).

To get over this restriction is fairly simple, changing my computer's default DNS by other ones (Google, OpenDNS, ....)

My problem here is that the DHCP announced DNS was my router (which itself got it's DNS from my ISP) so when i do want to access a computer by it's host name. It won't work anymore.

Is there a solution to use a third party DNS (Google, etc...) to resolve distant domain names and for the ones unknown by this DNS fallback to my default DNS (in my case, my router)

I already tried to setup a custom DNS in the IPv4 windows settings as the primary and my router as a secondary router but it does not work (the names unknown by the first DNS are not resolved using the second one).

My router is provided by my ISP and I can't change it's DNS configuration.

I'm searching here for existing and possibly native solutions, as i could install my own DNS server or even alter my host file (the latter can be a pain if a website changes it's IP address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up a DNS server inside the network and point all local resources at it you should be able to resolve resources internally and externally. You could run DNS on an old computer using Windows Server or Linux.

You do not need to change your router DNS settings. What you need to change are your router DHCP settings that issue the DNS settings. If you cannot do this you can assign all IP settings staticly or turn off the router DHCP and use your own DHCP server (presumably running on the same PC).

Comment: I do have a raspberry type B available, i'll look how to properly configure that.

Comment: That should do it.